# solving recurrence with $\Theta$: $T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{2}) + \Theta n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

### Solving Recurrence with $\Theta$

If $f(n)=\Theta n$, what exactly is $f(n)$?

This is what's throwing me off. I'm trying to solve using **the master theorem**.

> $$\mathrm{T}(n) = 3\mathrm{T}(\frac{n}{2}) + \Theta n$$

Answer (score 0):

$\Theta(n)$
is a function $f(n)$ for which
there are positive constants
$a$ and $b$ such that
$an < f(n) < bn$
for all large enough $n$.